# python numpy isin() function return wrong result

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I used `np.random.choice(datasize, n_train_data)` to shuffle dataset and split. As to test dataset:

```
np.random.seed(99)

dataset_index = np.arange(datasize)
train_index_arr = np.random.choice(dataset_index, n_train_data)
mask = ~np.isin(dataset_index, train_index_arr))
val_index_arr = dataset_index[mask]
```

However it return wrong result. Please kindly refer to the code below:

```
idx = np.random.choice(range(1000), 300)
sum(~np.isin(np.arange(1000), idx))
>> 742 # expected result: 700
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `replace = False` so that the choices you make don't go back into the choice pool

```
idx = np.random.choice(range(1000), 300, replace = False)
sum(~np.isin(np.arange(1000), idx))
Out[]: 700
```